# Creating an event and extracting data from XML file

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

Am trying to create an event that shall be inserting data from table1 into another table2 every three hours that meets a specific criteria. The criteria is for all data whose 'delivery_status' in table1 = 1000012004011312, to be sent to table1 every 3 hours.

The Event is as follows:

```
CREATE EVENT Resend_Undelivered_Messages

    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 HOURS

    DO

    INSERT INTO table2 (user_id, timestamp, dest_msisdn, text_message, sender_name, link_id, correlator, send_time, service_id, product_id, client)        

        SELECT (user_id, timestamp, dest_msisdn, text_message, sender_name, link_id, correlator, send_time, service_id, product_id, client)        

       FROM table1

       WHERE delivery_status ('result') = '1000012004011312';
```

The table structure for table1 (which is also similar to table2) is as follows:

[image]

Unfortunately for me, the 'delivery_status' in table2 is in XML format as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns1:sendSmsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/local"><ns1:result>1000012004011312
```

How can I successfully create a  Event that shall be doing this for me and be able to extract the "RESULT" in the XML file from table2?

Comment: the event function just transfer data from table1 to table2.so what is the relation with xml here?

Comment: The problem is that in table1 there are some messages that are not successfully delivered. This is denoted by their delivery status which indicates whether the result of sending them was successful or not, unfortunately, the delivery status in table1 is in xml format and am unable to extract the 'result' in the xml response to check whether the message shall be resent again, if it was unsuccessful the first time sent.

Comment: The delivery status you can see in the table structure above, is in xml format as shown above and not like '1000012004011312' as would want.

Comment: What am trying to do is extract the result ('1000012004011312') in the xml, as this denotes the delivery status of the message sent and want to use it to create my event. Thank You for response

Comment: so you have to parse the status value right and then process the event query?

Comment: Basically, the Delivery_status is in an XML DATA COLUMN as shown above